# Dados do PHP em HTML5 sem refresh?

Tags: php, html5

Como eu poderia fazer com que esse mesmo SELECT fosse execultado em arquivo.html e não arquivo.php, poderia puchar os dados de um php com javascript, jquery ou algo do tipo só não queria a extenção PHP.

Como posso fazer isso?

```html
<select name="ativo" action="">
    <?php while($reg = $query->fetch_array()) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $reg["id"]?>"> <?php echo $reg["prof"]?> </option>
    <?php }?>
</select>
```

Comment: Porque? Qual o motivo? existe mais ai é um junção de PHP com Javascript?

Comment: O motivo seria deixar a página mais dinamica e limpa.

Comment: Amaral dá independente da extensão, por exemplo, você pode carregar a sua página normalmente e com Ajax carregar o `Select` o seu contexto ta muito amplo pode colocar realmente o que precisa?

Comment: POR EXEMPLO: TENHO UM FORM DE BUSCA SEM REFRE ONDE TEM UM INPUT E UM BUTTON NORMALMENTE E UMA CLASS ONDE MOSTRA O RESULTADO PUXANDO DO BANCO.

Comment: Você pode criar um html simples com ajax para pegar as informações de um outro lugar de tempos em tempos e adicionar dinamicamente essas informações no select

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer algo deste tipo:

**arquivo.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="">
        <select name="ativo">
        </select>
    </form>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "select.php",
                success: function(resposta) {
                    $("form select[name='ativo']").html(resposta);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Dentro da segunda tag `script` tem duas funções, a primeira `$(document).ready(function() {` espera até que toda a página seja carregada para executar o bloco de código.. A segunda `$.ajax({` fará uma requisição AJAX ao arquivo dinâmico na sua aplicação para pegar os options do select que você deseja popular.

E no arquivo select.php que será o responsável por gerar os options, você faz isso:

**select.php**

```
<?php

while($reg = $query->fetch_array()) {
    echo '<option value="'.$reg["id"].'">'.$reg["prof"].'</option>'.PHP_EOL;
}

?>
```

**NOTA:** A primeira tag script é a que inclui no documento o plugin jquery, sem ela o script não funciona.

Comment: Se quiser diminuir ainda mais este arquivo **html**, você pode pegar tudo que tem entre `<script type="text/javascript">` e `</script>` e salvar dentro de um arquivo separado **select.js**.

Comment: Nem testei mas acredito que é isso mesmo, e já vou agradecendo Valeu mesmo Salvou uns 5 dias da minha vida. Vou testar e posto resposta. Obrigado Whatyson Neves - Quem sabe, sabe, pega as explicações no ar! NevesExpert!

Comment: Neves, só tem um pequeno problema, se ainda puder dar essa força... A função do select está registrando no DB o ID e não a opção escolhida no formulario, o que posso fazer?

Comment: Você quer adicionar o $reg[prof] ? é só apagar esse trecho `value="'.$reg["id"].'"`.

Comment: PERFEITO!!! VALEU Whatyson VOCÊ É FODA!